# How do I get multiple paperclip uploads to display in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, paperclip

I'm very new to programming and have followed [this screencast](http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/paperclip-with-rails-3) at emersonlackey.com on adding multiple paperclip uploads for a record. It all works great but I can't figure out how to display the uploaded images in the records show page.

They display fine on the edit page using:

```
<%= f.fields_for :venuephotos do |photo| %>
    <% unless photo.object.new_record? %>
      <p>
        <%= link_to image_tag(photo.object.venuephoto.url(:thumb)), photo.object.venuephoto.url(:original) %>
        <%= photo.check_box :_destroy %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I've used paperclip in other models but they are the standard each record only has one upload so the images display fine with <%= @model.photo.url %> type call but I cant figure out this other way.

Any help is much apprectiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
<% for asset in @post.assets %>

  <%= link_to image_tag(asset.asset.url(:thumb)), asset.asset.url(:original) %>

<% end %>
```

as per the code that goes along with the screencast.

https://github.com/Emerson/Multiple-File-Uploads-with-Paperclip-and-Rails-3/blob/master/app/views/posts/show.html.erb

Comment: thanks for the answer it works great! I'm super new to this and didn't know the source is all on there so double thanks!